# Call a subroutine in C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

could anyone please help me - I'm new to C# console apps, and trying to define a subroutine to replace a string of text in a file.

I keep getting the error though:

`Error  CS0119  'Program.Main(string[])' is a method, which is not valid in the given context   SSReplace   d:\users\mtait\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SSReplace\SSReplace\Program.cs`

Thanks for any help,

Mark

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SSReplace
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SSReplace.Program.Main.ReplaceInFiles("D:\\users\\mtait\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\SSReplace\\test_fic_ISUK.txt", "Begin", "Begin2");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces text in a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">Path of the text file.</param>
    /// <param name="searchText">Text to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="replaceText">Text to replace the search text.</param>
    public void ReplaceInFiles(string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You've got your Namespace mixed up: `ReplaceInFiles` is not inside `Main` - just `Program.ReplaceInFiles`will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark your method as static:

```
public static void ReplaceInFiles
```

A static method can't call an instance method, because there is no instance of `Program` created.

To call the method, just use its name `ReplaceInFiles` since it is in the same namespace and in the same class. No need to use the full `SSReplace.Program.Main` before it.

From C# Specifications:

> A method declared with a static modifier is a static method. A static
>   method does not operate on a specific instance and can only directly
>   access static members.
>
> A method declared without a static modifier is an instance method. An
>   instance method operates on a specific instance and can access both
>   static and instance members. The instance on which an instance method
>   was invoked can be explicitly accessed as this. It is an error to
>   refer to this in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

First: there is no such thing as a subroutine in C#, it´s called a *method*.

Second: A method (as any other member) is defined in a *class* and thus belongs to either an *instance* of that class or the *class itself* (`static` member). Thus write this instead:

```
var p = new Program();  // create a new instance of Program
p.ReplaceInFiles(myFile, "Begin", "Begin2"); // call the method on that instance
```

As you´re already *in* the namespace `SSReplace` you can also omit the part from your code.

Alternativly make your method `static`. Then you can call it like this:

```
Program.ReplaceInFiles(myFile, "Begin", "Begin2");
```

Note that there is neither the namespace nor the name of the `Main`-method. However even the `Program`-part is optional, making the following valid also:

```
ReplaceInFiles(myFile, "Begin", "Begin2");
```